# Excel/VBA Remove text from ThieWorkbook.Name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a copy of an excel file through use of a marco but amend text after the current file name when saving.  I have a macro that works, but it adds the file extension to the file name before I can amend text to it.

EG- my file is named "MyCurrentFile.xlsm", when I save it it adds the date, but keeps names the file "MyCurrentFile.xlsm01-14-16.xlsm".

Can I somehow remove the first .xlsm?

Code:

```
Sub Save_With_Todays_Date()
'
' Save_With_Todays_Date Macro
' Save a copy of the workbook with todays date at the end.

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & _
    ThisWorkbook.Name & _
    Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Workbook.FullName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834975.aspx) and parse off the extension.

```
Dim fpfn as String
fpfn = ThisWorkbook.FullName
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
    Filename:=Left(fpfn, InStrRev(fpfn, Chr(46)) - 1) & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy"), _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

I would recommend leaving the extension off the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) and let the [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) assign the correct extension. Hardcoding the extension reduces functionality and can result in an incorrect extension being applied to a SaveAs.

Answer (score 0):

ThisWorkbook.Name = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsm")